# Error 502, phpinfo() directing to 7.4 when 8.1 is installed (File not found)

Tags: php, nginx

I'm setting up a web server. I have a freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04, `nginx` (welcome page works), and `php-fpm` which installed php8.1 and php-fpm8.1.

To test PHP, I created a `/var/www/<my domain>/info.php` which just includes:

```
<?php
phpinfo(); ?>
```

Browsing to this page gives **Error 502 - Bad Gateway**.

Checking /var/log/nginx/error.log shows this:

```
connect() to unix: /var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

I verified that `/var/run/php` contains `php8.1-fpm.sock` but indeed not `php7.4-fpm.sock`

What is causing the request to look for php7.4?
How can I fully configure 8.1 so as not to be reliant on old/multiple versions of php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the **path** of the fpm php module to use in **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default** config file:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
    # Nginx php-fpm sock config:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    ...
}
```

So edit "/etc/nginx/sites-available/default" and change from

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
```

to

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
```

and restart nginx

Comment: Thank you, this worked! The issue was that I copied a tutorial that used the 7.4 path in the config file.

Comment: @WileyRush Please consider marking the answer as accepted if it solved your issue.

Comment: Done! Sorry, didn't realize I had unlocked that ability.